# Custom fonts not rendered in bold or italic in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

I'm trying to load local fonts with custom names. Everything works perfectly in all browsers except IE, as always. The font isn't being rendered in **bold** or *italic*. I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/maitreyjukar/5ga5k2oa/

I am loading the font using the following CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: k_Arial;
    src: local("Arial"), 
        local("Helvetica"), 
        local("sans-serif");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

for all combinations of font-weight and font-style.

Comment: hope you are not missing on `.eot` format files in your font folder, which is specifically needed for IE.

Answer (score 1):

This is not only not an IE-specific issue it doesn't work on other browsers like Firefox. 
Just write one font-face Rule istead of four like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: k_Arial;
src: local("Arial"), 
    local("Helvetica"), 
    local("sans-serif"); 
}
```

Here is My Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/deepak__yadav/1eed9na5 i hope you will understand what you did wrong.

Comment: I don't think that would be the right thing to do. Whenever we use a custom font we need to tell the browser how it should look when it is made bold or italic. In case we don't, the browser itself will try to fake those styles. You can see the difference between the rendered font glyphs here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/maitreyjukar/5ga5k2oa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an IE-specific issue - I'm on Firefox 38 and it doesn't work here either...

[`local` sources](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) are usually used to search on a user's machine before pointing to a URL, in order to speed things up.

However, you seem want to solely use locally installed fonts with a certain fallback order.
To achieve this, you could simply do the following:

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Bonus tip: Combine the `bold` and `italic` classes and you don't need an additional class `bolditalic`.

**[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15doy4ak/1/)**

Comment: Yes, agreed that I should use local fonts in the simple way. The only reason why this was being done was to follow a protocol for all fonts being used in the project.
Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

you can define your font like below example, this will work in all the browsers.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'ProximaNovaRegular';
        src: url('../fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('../fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.svg#ProximaNovaRegular') format('svg');
    }
```